# Windows 10 on 2008 R2 Hyper-V - No network adapter

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

i have an Windows Server 2008 R2 which is running as an Hyper-V host here. I tried to migrate a Windows 10 physical notebook to an Hyper-V guest by using the Disk2Vhd tool from Technet. It's booting fine and all apps are running as usual, but there are no network and sound adapters anymore, which is why i cannot access the internet from inside the machine. The integration services are installed and i also tried to use a legacy network adapter, but still there are no adapters visible.

So my question: is Windows 10 not supported/running on Hyper-V 2008 R2 or can this be fixed, e.g. by reinstallation of the os? We have some Windows 8/8.1 machines running which are running fine, so i cannot find a reason which deters Windows 10 to do so, too.

Thanks for your help!